# Validating HQL query without executing it

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

A user stores an HQL into DB. Later, the query is executed like this:

```
org.hibernate.Query query
query = sessionFactory.currentSession.createQuery(sqlQuery)
List rowsSelected = query.list()
```

Is there a way to validate user input HQL?